# How can I upgrade PHP 5.328 to PHP 7.4.9 to work with Oracle 11g?

Tags: php, upgrade, oci8

I have a PHP app running on a server using PHP  5.3.28 and it runs fine. However It has been requested by our security folks to upgrade to PHP 7.4.9. I have installed it but I get the error below:

**Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in D:\webroot\base4\external\ftof\index.php:217 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in **D:\webroot\base4\external\ftof\index.php** on line 217

I think this has to do with the OCI8 which is missing in PHP 7.4.9.

Can someone please give me a step-by-step method for updating this application to the newer PHP version?

Comment: Hello! I've been developing with php for many years, and I did a couple googles, I'm not sure if I have the answer you need, but you might need to either install a package for php that has the oracle connection functions, or install a flavor of php that has those functions included. See here: https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-php.html Again. I'm not too sure about a complete guide, as I don't have enough information about your server, but this link should get you the info you need.

Comment: Also, see this guide for writing a good question, it'll get your questions answered faster and keep your question from being downvoted, you have a good question for sure: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The Windows PHP 7.4.9 bundles do have the php_oci8_12c.dll extension.  Where do you have the additional Oracle client libraries installed?  And have you enabled (uncommented) the extension in your php.ini?

Comment: This appears to be the only one that is installed with PHP 7.4.9:     php_oci8_12c.dll 
        C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.4.9_x86\ext      I did uncomment this dll.